# Facebook (#506) Duplicate Status Message

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8

I have a wp8 application that is posting to Facebook. I put a rescue to prevent the error of posting the same message twice. I would like to have my app just notify the user and move on, but I cannot seem to rescue this error.

```
fb.PostCompleted += (o, args) =>
        {
            if (args.Error != null)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>MessageBox.Show(args.Error.Message));
                return;
            }

            var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)args.GetResultData();
            _lastMessageId = (string)result["id"];

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Message Posted successfully");


            });
        };
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters["message"] = "hi";
        var message = "Any Status message";

        fb.PostTaskAsync("me/feed", parameters);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem?

Comment: Do you have any code to share? That would help us a lot.

Comment: @Shadowfax: when i post a duplicate status message on fb through my app then always show error like :((OAuthException - #506) (506) Duplicate status message).

Comment: So what's the problem? If you'll try to post the same status in a short interval, fb wont allow you to do that. What exactly you want?

Comment: Actually, i want it to use for some location tracking app for latitude and longitude at interval for every 30 second.

Comment: Some one suggest me this link, But i did't understand the "fbResult" here: https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/issues/119

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just ignore the error?

```
        fb.PostCompleted += (o, args) =>
        {
            if (args.Error != null)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            { 
                var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)args.GetResultData();
                _lastMessageId = (string)result["id"];

                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Message Posted successfully");
                });
            }
        };
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters["message"] = "hi";
        var message = "Any Status message";

        fb.PostTaskAsync("me/feed", parameters);
```

You can also dig into the `args.Error` to check what kind of error message is given. This way you can decide not to show anything when it's a duplicate post error

Comment: But main problem is that duplicate status message not posting on facebook :).

Comment: So want you try to achieve is to post every 30 seconds the geo location of a person to fb, even if the location is still the same?

Comment: may be location can change in 30 second or remain same.